# android - Error: PERMISSION DENIED FOR THE ATTACHMENT

Tags: java, android

I am trying to attach a pdf file with my Gmail. But the problem is, it always shows a toast message which says "PERMISSION DENIED FOR THE ATTACHMENT". I tried on some different emails like Yahoo, but the file is still not being attached.

This is my Code for the Attachment:

```
case R.id.emailPdf:
                try {
                    String filename = "SampleFile1.pdf";
                    File filelocation = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + getPackageName() + "/files/", filename);
                    filelocation.setReadable(true, false);
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(filelocation);
                    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
                    String to[] = {""};
                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);

                    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."), 12);
                    break;

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

These are the permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I used the debugger, and I observed that the file is being read from the file location but dont know why its not getting attached.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the necessary runtime and manifest permissions to allow you to read files from disk?

Comment: Yes I added these permissions  in the AndroidManifest.xml file. @cricket_007

Comment: post your logtrace

Comment: @NehaBeniwal in which device you are run app?

Comment: As of Android 23, you also need **runtime** permissions, though

Comment: @VishalThakkar I am using the physical android phone, I am not running on the emulator.

Comment: @cricket_007   Can you please post these permissions that you are talking about.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @cricket_007   As I click on the email link, my device opens various email options like Gmail and all. But as I press Gmail, its gives a toast, as I said earlier in the post.

Comment: I'm not sure how that is related. Your app can't open the file in order to attach it to Gmail

Comment: @cricket_007   The file is opened in a PDF view in the application and I have an email link to that. Thus, my file reads the file from the location, creates an intent, but cannot attach.

Comment: On which android version you are running your app?

Comment: Android Studio 2.3.1,  CompiledSDKVersion: 25   @Michal_196

Comment: @NehaBeniwal From above comments I can make you are testing app on an Android device. Which android version your device is running on?

Comment: Its 5.1 Lollipop.   @Michal_196

Comment: @NehaBeniwal i have posted sample code of select photo from gallary using runtime permission for >23  check it

Comment: @NehaBeniwal hope its help you

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

Create method to check runtime permission.

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public boolean checkExternalPermission() {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Write external storage permission is necessary to read gallery pictures!!!");
                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now on attach button click:

```
   boolean result = checkExternalPermission();
            if (result) {
                activeGallery();
            }
```

Create method to open gallery like below:

```
 /**
 * to gallery
 */
private void activeGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}
```

Now handle permission result like below:

```
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                activeGallery();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//code for deny


        }
            break;

    }
}
```

Now handle activity result like below for your selected attachment:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver()
                            .query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                    null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    cursor.close();
//                    MyImage image = new MyImage();
//                    image.setTitle("Test");
//                    image.setDescription(
//                            "test choose a photo from gallery and add it to " +
//                                    "list view");
//                    image.setDatetime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    File file = new File(picturePath);
                    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

                    Product product = new Product(catID, "custom", "#1111", imageUri.toString(), "15000", "30%", 0);
                    dBhelper.createPRODUCT(product);
                    imageList.add(0, product);
//                        imageList.add(0, imageUri);
                        setimage(imageUri.toString(), imgview, true);
//                    imageList.add(0, picturePath);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


//                    images.add(image);
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

And finally declare below global variable:

```
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
 public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 3;
```

Make sure below permission you have define in manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: The question only wants to read from disk, though, and isn't using the gallery or images

Comment: @cricket_007 yes buddy i think she is getting problem with runtime permission.so i have given sample for  it and if pick image from gallery its also using storage permission

Comment: Write permission isn't needed for email attachments, so while a useful example, it doesn't fully answer the question, that's all I'm saying